# AWS Glue is not able to read JSON Snappy files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, apache-spark, aws-glue

I'm having issues reading data with a AWS Glue Job in PySpark:

Data is sent from a AWS firehose (sample data) to a s3 bucket, stored as JSON and compressed with snappy-hadoop.

I'm able to read data from legacy Spark dataframe with spark.read.json() but this won't work with Glue Dynamic Frame (schema is not parsed at all) using *from_catalog* or *from_options* method :

**Spark Legacy DataFrame**

```
# import from legacy spark read
spark_df = spark.read.json("s3://my-bucket/sample-json-hadoop-snappy/")
spark_df.printSchema()

- result:
root
 |-- change: double (nullable = true)
 |-- price: double (nullable = true)
 |-- sector: string (nullable = true)
 |-- ticker_symbol: string (nullable = true)
 |-- year: integer (nullable = true)
 |-- dt: date (nullable = true)
```

**Glue DynamicFrame**

```
# import from glue options
options_df = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_options(
  connection_type="s3",
  connection_options = {"paths": ["s3://my-bucket/sample-json-hadoop-snappy/"]},
  format="json"
)
options_df.printSchema()


- result:
root
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use spark legacy in the glue job also and if you want to perform operations on glue libraries only then read using spark then convert the df into dynamic frame.

```py
df = spark.read.json("s3://my-bucket/sample-json-hadoop-snappy/")
from awsglue.dynamicframe import DynamicFrame
DynF = DynamicFrame.fromDF(df, glueContext, "df")
```

Currently snappy compression is supported with parquet files only in Glue libs.

Comment: I'll lose the ability to use the Glue Bookmark feature though ? Do you have a link with format and compression support ? I haven't found any mention to this on aws docs ?

Comment: If this is required, you can raise a support ticket they will confirm you on the same. Also, you can raise a feature request for adding snappy compression support for json too.

Comment: How would one know which compression is supported for json ?

Comment: On aws documentation page it says snappy supported for orc and parquet...for json you can use gzip

Comment: Well, it seems not supported indeed. I'm not sure to which documentation page you are referring as I was unable to find any information on that topic. However it works now in gzip, thanks for your help